# store files to filepicker.io from the command line?

Tags: command-line, automation, filepicker.io

I have a bunch of files, I'd like to push them all to filepicker and use various convert options to manipulate them.

How do I automate this process? Is there a way to do this outside of javascript with a traditional scripting language I can run from the command line?

Comment: Short answer: Sure.  Longer answer: I imagine you're going to use *some* kind of language.  What's your preference?  VBScript or Powershell (Windows)?  Bash (Linux/MacOS)?  Visual Basic or C#?  Perl?  Something else entirely?

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com ? Good luck.

Comment: My ideal language would be perl on linux commandline. My question is how do I authenticate and what are the urls to go against? The docs expose only a javascript interface.

Comment: @shelter I haven't tried anything as the docs expose only the javascript interface. I've asked here as the filepicker docs direct me to post here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this is as a POST to /api/store/S3 with the contents of the file. For instance

```
curl -F fileUpload=@test.html 'https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3?key={{apikey}}&filename=myCoolFile.html'
```

There are other tools that perform similar actions, such as https://github.com/uams/geturl, but the mechanism they use (posting to /api/path/storage) is out of date.

Overall, you can use this functionality, but the urls may change. We're fairly happy with the /api/store/[provider] syntax, but may change before release

Comment: very nice, thanks. One question though, is posting to FP like this outside of the defined API likely to work in the long term? Why not expose this API publicly?

Comment: For all those interested the solution is very basic, POST to https://www.filepicker.io/api/path/storage with the params `apikey` and `fileUpload`. Not sure why filepicker doesn't expose this in their docs.

Comment: Just haven't gotten around to doing it, closing down a number of improvements to the javascript and messaging before pushing more on the server-side APIs, libraries, and docs.

I'd actually recommend hitting /api/store/S3 instead, same parameters, that's the url spec we're using going forward

Comment: Is that coming in the future, or do you mean it should be available now? When I try /api/store/S3 I get back the response 'Invalid Application' rather than valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks though you do realize those are NOT actually the same parameters, as you claimed.

Comment: Sorry man, just tested and that doesn't seem to work, still get 'Invalid Application', also I can't agree with your comment, geturl seems to use the old URL and params: https://github.com/uams/geturl/blob/master/geturl#L63

Comment: Yes, my earlier comment was overly hasty. I updated the answer to be more correct. If you are getting "Invalid Application," check to make sure your API key is valid

Comment: It still works for me. Is there anyway we can get the url of uploaded item ?

Comment: The answer in the post is still correct, and will return a JSON object containing the URL of the uploaded file